# Use JSXCompressor in Angular Project

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular JS. Could you please let me know how can use function `JXG.decompress(jxgcompressed)` from [JSXCompressor](https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph/tree/master/JSXCompressor) library in my Angular Module?

Answer (score 1):

The open source library JSXGraph (http://jsxgraph.org) contains utilities to read files which
have been compressed by the ZLIB (http://zlib.org) library. That means, JSXGraph has a pure
JavaScript implementation of deflate, unzip and base64_decode

```
      <?php
      function jxgcompress($filename) 
       {   
       if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $base64 = 
       base64_encode(gzcompress(rawurlencode(file_get_contents($filename)),9));
    echo "var jxgcompressed = " . $base64 . ";\n";
      } else {
    throw new Exception("$filename not found");
    }
   }
  ?>

  <?php 
  jxgcompress("./helloworld.js");
 ?>
```

Comment: It is not answering my question. My question is: is there any way to use the same JSXCompressor in my Angular Module?